# Find the generating function for $c_n = na_{n-1}$

Tags: generating-functions

Let $A(x)$ be the generating function of the sequence $(a_n)$. What is the generating function of the sequence:
$$
c_n = na_{n-1}
$$

In principle I know these rules:

$$
GF(a_{n-1}) = xA(x)\\
GF(na_n) = xA'(x)
$$

I am not sure how to combine these two though, my idea would have been to basically first compute the generating function for $a_{n-1}$ and then simply apply the second rule (i.e. differentiate the first line) to get something like this:

$$
C(x) = x*(xA(x))' = x(A(x) + xA'(x))
$$

Can someone tell me if that is a valid approach or otherwise point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 1} n a_{n-1} x^n 
&= \sum_{n \ge 1} (n-1) a_{n-1} x^n + \sum_{n \ge 1} a_{n-1} x^n \\
&= x \sum_{n \ge 1} (n-1) a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + x \sum_{n \ge 1} a_{n-1} x^{n-1} \\
&= x \sum_{n \ge 0} n a_n x^n + x \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n x^n \\
&= x^2 A'(x) + x A(x)
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that really clears things up!